# Apache exact url only

Tags: apache

I have the following apache config:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName someUrl

    DocumentRoot /usr/local/upload
 </VirtualHost>
```

this works but gives access to everything. The directory has pictures in. Is it possible to make it so the exact URL is required to gain access?

For example:

```
 http://someUrl.com/image.jpg
```

would allow you to view the image but:

```
 http://someUrl.com/
```

would give a 405.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable indexes on the directory.  Your config would look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName someUrl

    DocumentRoot /usr/local/upload
    <Directory /usr/local/upload>
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This would give you a standard `403 Forbidden` response for a directory request.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you'd want a "*405 Method Not Allowed*" error, but one way to do that is to use mod_rewrite's `R` flag:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=405]
```

Comment: sorry my bad i did mean 403. Thanks for this tho always good to know how to rewrite to 405